# Why do we simulate touches in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitouch

I find this code interesting. But I didn't understood why do we simulate touches in UIWebView?

```
enter code here
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head>\
<body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];

[self performSelector:@selector(touchInView:) withObject:videoView afterDelay:3];

}

- (void)touchInView:(UIView*)view{
UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] initInView:view];
UIEvent *eventDown = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

[touch.view touchesBegan:[eventDown allTouches] withEvent:eventDown];

[touch setPhase:UITouchPhaseEnded];
UIEvent *eventUp = [[UIEvent alloc] initWithTouch:touch];

[touch.view touchesEnded:[eventUp allTouches] withEvent:eventUp];

[eventDown release];
[eventUp release];
[touch release];
}
```

Comment: just guessing: maybe to "autostart" the youtube-video after 3 seconds what happens if you dont call the touchInView-method? or whats the difference?

Comment: @thomas, yes - autostart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like I posted in the comment to answer that question: It is for "autostarting" a youtube-video.